# Convert result of mysql query into nested php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a Mysql query:

```
SELECT 
    `pcm`.`ContactMechanismId` AS `ContactMechanismId`,
    `tel`.`AreaCode` AS `AreaCode`,
    `tel`.`PhoneNbr` AS `PhoneNbr`,
    `tel`.`Extension` AS `Extension`,
    `cmt`.`ContactMechanismTypeName` AS `ContactMechanismTypeName`,
    `c`.`DialingCode` AS `DialingCode`,
    `rt`.`RoleTypeName` AS `RoleTypeName`,
    `cmpt`.`ContactMechanismPurposeTypeName` AS `ContactMechanismPurposeTypeName`
FROM
    `PartyContactMechanisms` AS `pcm`
        INNER JOIN
    `Telephones` AS `tel` ON `pcm`.`ContactMechanismId` = `tel`.`ContactMechanismId`
        INNER JOIN
    `ContactMechanisms` AS `cm` ON `cm`.`ContactMechanismId` = `pcm`.`ContactMechanismId`
        INNER JOIN
    `ContactMechanismTypes` AS `cmt` ON `cmt`.`ContactMechanismTypeId` = `cm`.`ContactMechanismTypeId`
        INNER JOIN
    `Countries` AS `c` ON `tel`.`GeoId` = `c`.`GeoId`
        INNER JOIN
    `PartyContactMechanismPurposes` AS `pcmp` ON `pcm`.`ContactMechanismId` = `pcmp`.`ContactMechanismId`
        INNER JOIN
    `RoleTypes` AS `rt` ON `rt`.`RoleTypeId` = `pcm`.`RoleTypeId`
        INNER JOIN
    `ContactMechanismPurposeTypes` AS `cmpt` ON `pcmp`.`PurposeTypeId` = `cmpt`.`PurposeTypeId`
```

The result I get from Mysql is

```
    +--------------------+----------+----------+-----------+--------------------------+-------------+---------------+---------------------------------+
| ContactMechanismId | AreaCode | PhoneNbr | Extension | ContactMechanismTypeName | DialingCode | RoleTypeName  | ContactMechanismPurposeTypeName |
+--------------------+----------+----------+-----------+--------------------------+-------------+---------------+---------------------------------+
|                  2 | 111      | 22222222 | 2222      | landline                 |         375 | customer      | common phone                    |
|                  2 | 111      | 22222222 | 2222      | landline                 |         375 | contractor    | common phone                    |
|                  2 | 111      | 22222222 | 2222      | landline                 |         375 | manufacturer  | common phone                    |
|                  2 | 111      | 22222222 | 2222      | landline                 |         375 | customer      | primary phone                   |
|                  2 | 111      | 22222222 | 2222      | landline                 |         375 | contractor    | primary phone                   |
|                  2 | 111      | 22222222 | 2222      | landline                 |         375 | manufacturer  | primary phone                   |
|                  2 | 111      | 22222222 | 2222      | landline                 |         375 | customer      | secretary phone                 |
|                  2 | 111      | 22222222 | 2222      | landline                 |         375 | contractor    | secretary phone                 |
|                  2 | 111      | 22222222 | 2222      | landline                 |         375 | manufacturer  | secretary phone                 |
|                  1 | 17       | 2905950  |           | landline                 |         375 | customer      | other phone                     |
+--------------------+----------+----------+-----------+--------------------------+-------------+---------------+---------------------------------+
```

I need is to convert the above result into the following array:

```
[
    [ContactMechanismId, AreaCode, PhoneNbr, Extension, ContactMechanismTypeName, DialingCode, RoleTypeName[], ContactMechanismPurposeTypeName[]
]
```

In the arrays `RoleTypeName[]` and `ContactMechanismPurposeTypeName[]` go ALL possible values for a certain `ContactMechanismId` from the corresponding column of the mysql result.

How can I do this?

Comment: post your mysql code here

Comment: provide your table structure and query you have

Comment: uuh, i'll try. problem is that it's a VERY simplified model of what's really happening... :)

Comment: You just need a loop and a couple of ifs, all you need to do on sql level is to order your results by the main fields. What exactly is your issue with implementing the code?

Comment: @Shadow, that's what i thought too, but was wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Better in what terms?

Comment: @Shadow, simpler + less load on the system.

Comment: guys, sorry, edited the question to add more clarity.

Comment: _“In the arrays RoleTypeName[] and ContactMechanismPurposeTypeName[] go ALL possible values for a certain ContactMechanismId from the corresponding column”_ – in that regard you might want to look into `GROUP_CONCAT`. (It won’t give you an “array” directly, because that’s rather impossible for SQL to do, but you can get all values separated by f.e. a comma – and that is easy to `explode` into an actual array again in PHP.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the select statement like bellow using [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT 
`pcm`.`ContactMechanismId` AS `ContactMechanismId`,
`tel`.`AreaCode` AS `AreaCode`,
`tel`.`PhoneNbr` AS `PhoneNbr`,
`tel`.`Extension` AS `Extension`,
`cmt`.`ContactMechanismTypeName` AS `ContactMechanismTypeName`,
`c`.`DialingCode` AS `DialingCode`,GROUP_CONCAT(
`rt`.`RoleTypeName`) AS `RoleTypeName`,GROUP_CONCAT(
`cmpt`.`ContactMechanismPurposeTypeName`) AS `ContactMechanismPurposeTypeName`
```

Then group the data using `GROUP BY`,You will get RoleTypeName and ContactMechanismPurposeTypeName as a comma seperated value.You can iterate using php loop and using [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to form the array

Comment: thanks! i'm not quite sure how to use `group by` in this case because if i use `GROUP BY ContactMechanismPurposeTypeName, RoleTypeName` at the end of the whole sql, i get the same result as if i didn't use `group_concat()` and `group by` at all. could you clarify please?

Comment: ok, i figured it out myself: i needed to group by `ContactMechanismId` and use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ...)`.

Comment: Sorry,my explanation is little bit confusing

Comment: it's ok, the most important thing is that i understood how to get it right. thanks!